# Django - table xxx has no column named xxx

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have problem with my form when I try save it in view then i see error: table core_order has no column named responsible_group_id. I made migrations, flush ect. but this not resolve my problem.

**Forms.py:**

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('responsible_group', 'responsible_user')

    def __init__(self, request_client_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['responsible_group'].choices = BLANK_CHOICE + tuple(
            Group.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name').exclude(id=1)) 
        self.fields['responsible_user'].choices = BLANK_CHOICE

        self.fields['responsible_group'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control input-block-level',
        })
        self.fields['responsible_user'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control input-block-level',
        })
```

**models.py:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    responsible_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    responsible_user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    finished_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    (...)
```

**views.py:**

```
def order_create(request, request_client_id):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_order = CreateForm(request_client_id, request.POST)
            if form_order.is_valid():
                obj = form_order.save(commit=False)

                (...)

                obj.responsible_group = form_order.cleaned_data["responsible_group"]
                obj.responsible_user = form_order.cleaned_data["responsible_user"]

                obj.save()

                # Redirect to Client profile
                return HttpResponse('')
```

**My traceback:**

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/panel/order/create/4/

Django Version: 1.8.8
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core',
 'api',
 'client',
 'registration',
 'avatar',
 'filer',
 'mptt',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'reversion')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')

    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
      132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\loc\PycharmProjects\CRM\core\views.py" in order_create
      537.                 obj.save()
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
      734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
      762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
      846.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
      885.                                using=using, raw=raw)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
      127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
      920.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
      974.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
      79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
      98.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
      685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
      64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "C:\Users\loc\dJangoEnvironment\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
      318.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

    Exception Type: OperationalError at /panel/order/create/4/
    Exception Value: table core_order has no column named responsible_group_id
```

Comment: Whats the `(...)` for in the saving part of your code? why do you do `commit=False` just to then set the fields manually?

Comment: Saying *I made migrations, flush etc* isn't really enough information. What migrations were created? Which migrations did you run? What is the current state of `./manage.py showmigrations`? Running `flush` isn't really helpful because it only removes data from the tables, it doesn't remove the tables themselves. If this is a test database, the easiest thing might be to drop the database, delete the migrations, recreate them and then run them.

Comment: @Alasdair delete database and create new one help but for development not productive(because i'cant drop all data i need fix this) - u have some else idea?

Comment: In production, you will need to make sure that your tables, migrations and models are all in sync. You might be able to do this by running the appropriate migrations, or you might need to run some SQL statements. You haven't shown enough information for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your migration file(s) and then rerun `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` afresh.